# composing Serializers + DSL

Tags: json4s

I've defined custom Jackson serializers and I have a Formats in scope to allow writing my types.

I'd like to compose an object. At first I tried:

```
val req =
  ("source" → asJValue(sources)) ~
  ("format" → asJValue(formats))
```

But that doesn't work because Formats doesn't work with asJValue.

So I am stuck with

```
val source = parse(write(sources))
val format = parse(write(formats))

val req =
  ("source" → source) ~
  ("format" → format)
```

Did I miss something?
Can someone show me a better way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This solution may work for you:

```
import org.json4s.Extraction.decompose

val req =
  ("source" → decompose(sources)) ~
  ("format" → decompose(formats))
```